# Upgrade from angular 2 to 4 create the system slow in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, asp.net-core

I, have upgrade the angular 2 to angular 4 using the below link

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/05/20/upgrading-from-angular-2-to-angular-4

On upgrade the loading page is slow as compare to the previous loading page.On load their are many js file has been loaded.

[image: angular 4 load js files]

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.47",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/node_modules",
    "typings"

  ],

  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

_layout.cstml

```
<script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="~/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

System.js

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Since, its load many js file and the system is slow. Can anyone tell me where I, am making mistake.

Comment: Don't reference `rxjs`, only reference the classes you need, i.e. `rxjs/Observable`. Also it's only slow when a) you have the Firefox/Chrome Developer Toolbars enabled and b) you have debugger attached to your ASP.NET Core application which serves the static files. Remove debugger from your Angular and only leave the debugger on your WebApi Application

Comment: Alternatively, configure your build pipeline do to do bundling/packaging, even for debug builds

Comment: Is their no other solution for this ?

Comment: No, that's how module loading works. For some reason rx.js doesn't ship with an umd module which is compatible with systemjs, so the loader always keeps loading the single files. And if you reference `rxjs` in one of your type script files, it loads every single file referenced by it, ending up something like 300 requests. See related [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you (or angular 4, dunno for sure) includes `rxjs/Rx` somewhere in the code.

This will force the systemjs loader to load every single file referenced by `Rx.js`, which includes all operators etc (see [here](https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.2.0/Rx.js)).

Instead narrow down the imports to only the files you really need. In most cases it's the `Observable` class.

so from

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

make it like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Alternatively bundle/package your files, even when developing. So the files will be packed into the modules and only one file per module will be loaded.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I bundle/package files ?? I, am using asp.net core

Comment: You should ask  a new question about it (but before you ask, do research and find out which of the module bundlers best suits your workflow and needs). It's quite complex and there are many ways to archive this and even more tools to use for that (webpack, systemjs, requirejs, jspm). Actually it's no different than when you bundle an angular 2 (or 4) application for release

Comment: I, have added system.js file . 'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs', is this I have to change ? If yes how can I change

Comment: No, that would only work if `import { ... } from 'rxjs';` is used from code, but angular itself references `from 'rxjs/xxx';` See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9359) for more details. One could easily fill a book of maybe 100+ pages describing all the bundlers, their differences and configurations, so it's not a topic which can be covered in a simple answer, and you'll have to dive into this topic anyways when you ship your completed application (bundling your app and your dynamically loaded angular 2 modules)